# Comment badge suggestion

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

Hi,

I would like to suggest a badge for stackoverflow, something like "Comment tracker".

**Reason**
When questions get answers and the questioner has a comment with further questions to the answer made, the answerer doesn't always get back to comment his/her answer. This might, in some cases lead to non-complete answer.

**Bronze suggestion** 
Replied with one comment more than once on 5 own answers

**Silver suggestion**
Replied with one comment more than once to 50 own answers

**Gold suggestion**
Replied with one comment more than once to 500 own answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I disagree. Extended comment discussion should be discouraged in favour of opening new questions, as more often than not protracted discussion tends to veer off topic.

> ... the answerer doesn't always get back to comment his/her answer. This might, in some cases lead to non-complete answer.

The StackExchange SuperCollider MultiDropDown is actually pretty useful for tracking comment replies to answers, even if the little (1) has disappeared. I think this works very well and is as much as is needed. Also, other people following the question can always add additional information.

> When questions get answers and the questioner has a comment with further questions to the answer made

Again, I don't think we should explicitly encourage asking additional questions in comments, except perhaps for clarification on the answer. There is a line to draw:

- Does it extend/clarify the original question? So did the OP ask, say, how to use such a feature, then when they ask about an answer it turns out they wanted something subtly different?
- Is it a request for minor clarification? You've used `char` could I use `int`?
- Is it an entirely different question.

If it's relevant to the question in hand, edit it into the question then edit your answer with additional information. If it is minor clarification, edit your answer. If it is a related, but different question, it should be a whole new question. There is nothing wrong with a question that begins like this:

> I asked yesterday how to do X [link]. Now I've got a question about Y.

Assuming of course it isn't a complete duplicate.

I am of course entirely biased. I like how SO works; specifically I like how it *isn't* phpBB, i.e. a massive thread 28 pages long which is mostly noise. In short, if you have 20 questions on X, the SO way is to ask 20 questions, not start a thread and reply endlessly until all 20 questions are answered.

Answer (score 0):

How would you track that the comment was useful or that it replied to another comment?

Regardless, the answer should be updated with the new details, not just a comment added.

Comment: the answer should be clear from the beginning to begin with, yet thats not the case. The answer might have comments that are not answered nor updated. Can keep track of it either by checking the amount of comments on own answers or checking when comments get voted upwards.